Is this layout for the power section alright?
I’m working with two buck converters (LMR51430XFDDCR) and am currently designing their layout. I’m unsure if there are any potential issues with my current design. I am aiming for a PCB as small as possible, but I don't fully understand how the two layouts of the converters interact with each other. Any insights or feedback would be greatly appreciated!


Texas Instruments recommended layout(datasheet):


You've got two capacitors of different values in the same size package which is usually a bad idea. The 100nF should be used to enable a smaller package size and a lower inductance loop, or if it doesn't do that, use two of the larger size. I also dislike the recommendation to put the capacitors besides the converter far from the ground pin connected by the narrow ground under the package. I'd probably put them on the backside directly between GND and VIN since that's the critical high frequency loop, but I'm sure their recommendation works.

And for my layout should I space the inductors more in order to prevent coupling between them or it's ok as it is?

What type are the inductors?

Sorry for the late reply! The inductors are 744314650 from Wurth Elektronik and XAL5050-103MEC from Coilcraft.

It's a shielded inductor and you're almost 1 cm apart so it's probably fine.
